# Javascript function to read url and to assign active class not working

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

my problem is about an internal menu I created in a wordpress website. I can't correctly assign an "active" class to a text links of the menu when I go to the third level pages.

I make an example that can help you to understand the problem:

url type structure: www.***.***/servizi-ai-privati/fisioterapia-riabilitazione

code of the menu item:

```
<a href="/servizi-ai-privati/fisioterapia-riabilitazione" class="active">
   <div id="fisioterapia-riabilitazione" class="menu_servizi_privati_sezione">
      <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/icona_fisioterapia.svg" 
         class="menu_servizi_icona">
      <h6>Fisioterapia e riabilitazione</h6>
   </div>
</a>
```

It works good when I am in this page and the menu item takes the "active" class I created.

url: http://www.test.com/servizi-ai-privati/fisioterapia-riabilitazione/massoterapia/

Menu item didn't take the active class.

I assign the active class with this js function:

```
jQuery(function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname,
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$"); // create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash if present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case trailing slash wasn't present there

        // now grab every link from the navigation
        jQuery('.menu_servizi_privati a ').each(function(){
        // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
            if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,' '))){
                jQuery(this).addClass(' active ');
            }
        });
    });
```

How do I have to change this function to make it read correctly the entire url? Sorry but I'm not so practiced with javascript. I hope I explained clearly my problem.

This is the full code of the menu I created:

```
<div class="cmsmasters_sidebar sidebar_layout_11 widget_menu_servizi_privati">
   <aside id="custom_html-3" class="widget_text widget widget_custom_html">
      <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">
         <div style="text-align: center">
            <div class="menu_servizi_privati">
               <a href="/servizi-ai-privati/prenota-visita">
                  <div id="prenota-visita" class="menu_servizi_privati_sezione">
                     <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/icona_prenota_visita.svg" class="menu_servizi_icona">
                     <h6>Prenota una visita</h6>
                  </div>
               </a>
               <a href="/servizi-ai-privati/visite-specialistiche">
                  <div id="visite-specialistiche" class="menu_servizi_privati_sezione">
                     <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/icona_visite_specialistiche.svg" class="menu_servizi_icona">
                     <h6>Visite specialistiche</h6>
                  </div>
               </a>
               <a href="/servizi-ai-privati/check-up">
                  <div id="check-up" class="menu_servizi_privati_sezione">
                     <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/icona_checkup.svg" class="menu_servizi_icona">
                     <h6>Check up</h6>
                  </div>
               </a>
               <a href="/servizi-ai-privati/fisioterapia-riabilitazione" class="active">
                  <div id="fisioterapia-riabilitazione" class="menu_servizi_privati_sezione">
                     <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/icona_fisioterapia.svg" class="menu_servizi_icona">
                     <h6>Fisioterapia e riabilitazione</h6>
                  </div>
               </a>
               <a href="/servizi-ai-privati/punto-prelievi">
                  <div id="punto-prelievi" class="menu_servizi_privati_sezione">
                     <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/icona_punto_prelievi.svg"     class="menu_servizi_icona">
                     <h6>Punto prelievi</h6>
                  </div>
               </a>
               <a href="/servizi-ai-privati/medici">
                  <div id="medici"     class="menu_servizi_privati_sezione">
                     <img src="/wp-    content/uploads/2017/09/icona_medici.svg" class="menu_servizi_icona">    
                     <h6>I medici</h6>
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </aside>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: The urls you specified in your question require authentication, so your website can't be verified. Please, post a bit more code to understand.

Comment: The url is only an example to let you understand the url I have. The website is not published so I can't write here the right url.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. You have many issues here.

First:
You are using `jQuery('.menu_servizi_privati a ')` but your a-tag is not within any container. Please provide more code or fix this issue.

Second:
You are using `this.href` which is providing the full URL, but you compare it to windows.location.pathname, which is providing only the URL path.

Third: Instead of removing trailing slashes, you should make sure that your website is reachable by only one URL version (URL redirecting). That's better for Google / SEO (unique content).

Solution:
Get rid off of the regex and fix the code. This is working perfectly fine for me. I rewrote the code a bit. When you need to specify `jQuery`, you can just replace the `$`-sign with `jQuery`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gpq3ptm3/

Comment: Hi Michael, I wrote above the entire code of the menu.

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the answer. And yes, this code should do it

Comment: Sorry but the function doesn't work both for the second level page and for the third level page.

Comment: I don't see any other level. Unfortunately, it is very hard to assist without having all the information. Just double check the output of the functions by debugging them. Make `console.log` to each variable to check the values